# How does these two notations differ in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and still kind of confused with some notations.

In the function header, i know that

```
func :: [Int] -> Int
```

indicates that the input is a list of integers and the output is an integer.

How does this differ from

```
func :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
```

I am asking because they seem to be same, and I wonder why we use different notations for something identical.

Comment: They are not the same. `Ord a => [a] -> a` means a function that produces a value of type `a` for a list of values of type `a` where `a` is any type that is totally ordered (has an `Ord` instance). `Int`s fit that definition, but so do many other types. You can use the second `func` on strings, floats, …

Comment: To further clarify your question: before Ryan's explanation, how would you have explained what `(Ord a) => [a] -> a` means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is very simple and as you have said, it takes a list of `Int` and returns a single `Int`.

The second one, however, can accept many different types for its input (including types you define yourself).

The key is `(Ord a)`. What this is saying is that it has to be a list of **orderable** types, and if it satisfies that requirement then it is a valid type that can be passed into this particular function.

The Ord typeclass includes the following members:

- `<`
- `<=`
- `>`
- `>=`

So

```
func :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
```

could potentially be a function that takes a list of orderable types and returns the maximum member of that list, as an example. This could be `[Int]`, `[Integer]`, `[Float]`, and many other things.